# Create Signed Cookies in Lambda@Edge for Restricted Distribution

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to parse requests in a `viewer-request` Lambda@edge – the incoming requests are unsigned and the Cloudfront Distribution has Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies) checked and enabled.

The idea is that I can determine whether the request to the S3 origin should be authorized right within the Lambda@Edge rather than requiring a prior request to a separate lambda to fetch the signed Cloudfront cookie.

Is there any way to authorize/sign the incoming request as it happens, or does Cloudfront deny requests without signed url queryparams or cookies before the Lambda@Edge is called?

Comment: *"The idea is that I can determine whether the request to the S3 origin should be authorized right within the Lambda@Edge"*  In that case, why do you need "restrict viewer access" enabled?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot if the user has a signed cookie already, pass the request through, otherwise, check if authorized. if so, redirect to the same url with `set-cookie` header so subsequent requests may pass through, and if not, deny request

Comment: There isn't a way to bypass Restrict Viewer Access.  An unauthorized request won't make it to the Viewer Request trigger -- it fires immediately after the cookies are used, to validate that the request is authorized.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks for the clarification – if you move your message to answers, I'd be happy to accept :)